# Relief for menubar

Tags: python, pygtk, gtk, gnome

I'm in the process of creating a Gnome pannel applet. I've added a menubar to the applet but it seems I can't set the relief on the menubar. Does anyone know how I can edit that?

I only want the relief to show when the bar is hovered or the submenu is collapsed.
This is how it looks now: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7i8C9.png

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind. Found it:

```
    gtk.rc_parse_string("""
        style "globalmenu_event_box_style"
        {
            GtkWidget::focus-line-width=0
            GtkWidget::focus-padding=0
        }
        style "globalmenu_menu_bar_style"
        {
            ythickness = 0
            GtkMenuBar::shadow-type = none
            GtkMenuBar::internal-padding = 0
        }
        class "GtkEventBox" style "globalmenu_event_box_style"
        class "GtkMenuBar" style:highest "globalmenu_menu_bar_style"
        class "GnomenuMenuBar" style:highest "globalmenu_menu_bar_style"
    """);
```